# Use multiple regions from ryanfitz/vogels

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I use [Ryan Fitz' Vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) NodeJS package to access DynamoDB. I have the same tables in multiple regions and I need to access these tables from a single NodeJS instance. How can I specify the region per table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each model you define can be configured with a unique dynamodb client instance.

```
// Define models
var Account = vogels.define('Account', {hashKey :'email'});
var Product = vogels.define('Product', {hashKey :'productId'});

// Configure account models to use us-east-1
var dynamodbEast = new AWS.DynamoDB({region : 'us-east-1');
Account.config({dynamodb: dynamodbEast});

// Configure product models to use us-west-1
var dynamodbWest = new AWS.DynamoDB({region : 'us-west-1');
Product.config({dynamodb: dynamodbWest});
```

Comment: This behaviour is also documented in the library's documentation (see https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels#configuration). Thanks for sharing your excellent library with the community. I like it a lot...